# VSTS REST API - GIT - Does Branch Exist?

Tags: git, rest, azure-devops

How can I tell if a branch exists in my vsts git repo using the REST API?

I see there's a ref endpoint, and I can filter the query for heads(branches) only, but how can I specific a branch name filter? Pulling back all the branch names and filtering on the client isn't a great answer.

I didn't find anything in the API docs at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/refs#just-branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation tells you:

> `filter` Git ref name filter. If you specify this parameter, only refs
>   that start with that string are returned.

So if you want to get the branch `develop` exists, you filter on `refs/heads/develop`.

Comment: ahhh.. that wasn't clear to me from reading the docs.  I knew I could get the branches by specifying "heads" as the filter, but not that I could append the branch name.  Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: `filter` should be `heads/{branch}` not `refs/heads/{branch}`